# Collision detection between ball & maze made dynamically from text file

Tags: java, android, maze

Ok so I am creating a ball tilting game, where you navigate a ball around a maze. The ball works, and is all good in the area however I am having some problems in the maze.

The maze is programmatically created through a .txt file that contains 1's and 0's (1's being walls, and 0's being floor.) I have a for loop that goes through the whole .txt file and places a white(wall) or black(floor) square at the proper coordinates on a canvas. This is similar to the apps-for-android Amazed game if you have seen it [link.](https://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/#git/Amazed/src/com/example/amazed) However, instead of placing wall-type detection on his tiles, he just resets the game and deducts a life point if the user rolls onto a 'void' tile.

However I am looking to have 'walls' and not 'voids'. Where if the ball touches the wall, it doesn't go beyond that point, but can still move freely on the other axis. Unless it hits a corner, of course.

The problem I am having is actually creating this detection. I have tried a number of ways but nothing so far has been successful or useful.

I have tried:
- Have an ArrayList of all of the coordinates of the wall tiles, and every game tick, it checks to see if the ball is touching one. However this just slowed the game down to a crawl and was just extremely terrible.
- Check to see what tile the ball is on, and if it's on a wall tile, to stop it on an axis but let it move freely on the other, however this still didn't work as there were some issues when the ball was to the right of the wall tile, but also under it, it couldnt move up, as the code detected it being under the ball.

And a few other ways but I really cannot remember! It's been a bit hectic.

So, I am asking, if anyone has any experience in this area could they please give me a push in the right direction? Im hoping to have the maze walls sorted by Tuesday however it's looking grim!

If you need any more information, please ask.

Thank you in advance for any and all replies.

Comment: What is the size of the maze? i.e. the text file is essentially a 2-dimensional array of what size by what size?

Comment: I'm no expert in game design and I have no prior experience. However, an ArrayList probably makes the app slow because every time you're looking for an element (i.e. contains()), you are essentially iterating over the whole list. So, storing the wall coordinates in a HashSet should make lookups faster. This is because internally a HashSet stores its content in a map which should hopefully give you a O(1) lookup time.

Comment: shaflex - my maze is 20x26. I'll have a look at HashSet though! thank you.

Comment: @user1463725 - I rolled back your edit because you deleted your entire question.  Anyone that may have a similar issue to what you encountered would not be able to find the answers provided.  The green checkmark on the answer below shows that it has been solved.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise that's how this website worked! Had an account for ages but only asked a few questions. Will keep in mind for the future. Thank you.

Comment: @user1463725 - no problem at all, it's why we are all here!  If you have any other questions on how the site works, http://stackoverflow.com/faq is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having an ArrayList that you have to iterate over, why not store the maze the same way you do the text file? Use a 2D boolean array filled with `true` for wall and `false` for floor, or vice versa.

This simplifies finding a wall considerably. All you have to do is figure out where in your grid the ball is. Then you can just check the cells immediately surrounding it. Even if you include diagonals(which probably isn't necessary for an all-90-degree maze), this equates to checking 8 booleans from an array, basically instant.

As for the axis issue, just stop movement in *that direction*. No need to freeze a whole axis. For instance, if the wall is right of you, just don't allow `x` to go higher. No reason to not let it lower unless there's a wall to the left.

This is just a general idea, though. Since it's homework, no code for you ;)

**Edit:**

The 2D array is just that, a `boolean[][]` which holds true in each of the spots where you want a wall to be. When you read in your text file, just assign it straight away.

Assuming each line in your text corresponds to an `y` row, and each 0/1 is the `x` for that column, when you read a `1`, assign `map[x][y] = true`.

I'm honestly not sure what else you need elaboration on. It's a common format to do simple tile-based maps, though. If you google "2d array tile map", you'll find several resources to help with it.

Comment: This sounds like a really good solution... This will be the next thing I try as soon as I get onto my computer. Thank you!

Comment: Reading over this again, I am trying something similar on my code right now, however could you elaborate on the 2D boolean array? Im not quite sure what you mean?